# Hibernation: computer shuts down completely, but powers back up in a couple of seconds

Tags: windows-7, hibernate

I like using hibernation on my Win 7 SP1 x64. But there's a problem: hibernation itself works fine, but after shutdown the computer powers back up in a couple of seconds, so I must wait for it and shut it down again during POST.
I don't even know how to start debugging it. Is it some hardware fault? A BIOS setting that's causing it? Any ideas?

Comment: I have this exact same problem, but it's very intermittent. Do you find that it *always* happens? i.e. if you clean boot the system and hibernate does it happen then? I sort of feel like this is a software issue but I also have not been able to track the source of the issue down. But then for me it only happens once every month or so.

Comment: Also, have you checked the windows Event Log?

Comment: @zelanix: I didn't check the event log, what's the point? The problem clearly happens after Windows shuts down entirely.  It's very persistent for me so far, tried like 20 times during 2 weeks and it happens every time.

Comment: Because you are assuming that you system is *off* when it is in hibernate. Actually software can schedule the machine to wake even from hibernation (see [here](http://www.dennisbabkin.com/wosb) for an example application that does just that).

Comment: @zelanix: fair enough, but shouldn't I be able to disable wake-up timers in BIOS setup? Also, I wouldn't know what to look for in the event log.

Comment: Another way to look at this is from the perspective of the [ACPI power states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface#Power_states). When you are in hibernate the CPU is actually in S4 mode which is a form of sleep state, not G2 or G3 which are the actual *off* states.

Comment: I don't think that the wake timers are disableable. You should find that the machine goes into hibernate mode with an event log message, and then shortly after that you may have a reason for wake. It's worth a look, anyway.

Comment: @zelanix: checked the log around hibernation entry, nothing suspicious.

Comment: Ok. Try running `powercfg –lastwake` from en elevated command prompt. This will determine if it is a hardware device waking the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of things that can cause this.  Take a look at [this](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-fix-computer-keeps-waking.htm) troubleshooting guide.

Comment: I've tried the steps from the guide 1 by 1, and finally have fixed the issue. What helped me was `powercfg -devicequery wake_armed` command. I've disabled "Allow this device to wake the computer" option for a couple devices, and turned out keyboard was causing this. I think it's some kind of BIOS bug or a motherboard hardware fault, because I wasn't touching the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

There's something called wake-on-lan. Check your BIOS for that and disable it. Also check the setting where it takes action after a power restore. That can trigger the computer to come on by itself. This would be especially prone if your incoming power is a little bit buggy.